# Adding a class from a controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im building a simple menu in Angular:

```
<ion-nav-view name="section"></ion-nav-view>
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-color-assertive tabs-icon-top">
    <div class="tabs">
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="menuClick(1)">
            <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
            Test
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="menuClick(2)">
            <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
            Favorites
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="menuClick(3)">
            <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i>
            Settings
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller that handles this view is:

```
app.controller('menu', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.menuClick = function(btn) {
        if(btn == 1) {
            $state.go('app.lists');
        }
        else if(btn == 2)
            $state.go('app.pay');

    }
});
```

How can I add a class to the button just pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the most easy way for this is to make additional variabile like `$scope.pressed`on `$scope` and use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) in template

And the code should looks like:

```
$scope.menuClick = function(btn) {
   $scope.pressed = btn;
   if(btn == 1) {
       $state.go('app.lists');
   }
   else if(btn == 2)
       $state.go('app.pay');
}
```

and HTML will looks like:

```
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-color-assertive tabs-icon-top">
    <div class="tabs">
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="menuClick(1)" ng-class="pressed === 1 ? 'your new class' : ''">
            <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
            Test
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="menuClick(2)" ng-class="pressed === 2 ? 'your new class' : ''">
            <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
            Favorites
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="menuClick(3)" ng-class="pressed === 3 ? 'your new class' : ''">
            <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i>
            Settings
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read a bit about ion-nav, and it seems it's utilizing ui-router library. So you can try to use:

```
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-color-assertive tabs-icon-top">
    <div class="tabs">
        <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="path.to.state1" ui-sref-active="class name if in state">
            <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
            Test
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="path.to.state2" ui-sref-active="class name if in state">
            <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
            Favorites
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="path.to.state3" ui-sref-active="class name if in state">
            <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i>
            Settings
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

ui-sref - generates link for state

ui-sref-active - a class that would be added if you are in this state.

The only right solution is to attach your buttons to a state.

As alternative you can do something like:

**$scope.$state = $state;** <-- in your controller. You should share $state object to your view.

```
<div class="tabs">
    <a class="tab-item" ng-class="{'active': $state.is('state.path.state1')}" ng-click="menuClick(1)">
        <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
        Test
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-class="{'active': $state.is('state.path.state2')}" ng-click="menuClick(2)">
        <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
        Favorites
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-class="{'active': $state.is('state.path.state3')}" ng-click="menuClick(3)">
        <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i>
        Settings
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more of a *jQuery-ish* type of solution but better if you don't need to clutter the `$scope` variable just for addition (or toggling) of css classes.

When calling a function in `ng-click` there is an implicit `$event` variable passed to the function called ([angular docs reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)) which is [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) object.

You can access the element using the `target` property [`MouseEvent.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and then execute jQuery function for [managing the classes on the DOM element](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/).

ex:

```
<div ng-click="clickHandler($event);"></div>

$scope.clickHandler = function($event) {
  var element = $($event.target);

  element.toggleClass('clicked');
}
```

Comment: The question was about tabs, your example toggles the class on a single item.

Comment: This answer is a general one, regarding the last sentence question - "How can I add a class to the button just pressed?"